# How to create a dynamic subnav

Tags: angular, vmware-clarity

I am using Angular 4 and am learning about the clarity design system.
Was wondering if anyone has managed to create subnav with dynamic links?
https://vmware.github.io/clarity/documentation/header#subnav

I am not sure how to go about this properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<nav class="subnav">
    <ul class="nav">
        <li class="nav-item" *ngFor="nav of navs">
            <a class="nav-link" routerLinkActive="active"
[routerLink]="nav.link">{{nav.title}}</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

and in your class :

```
  nav = [
       {link:'somewhere/dashboard',title:'Dashboard'},
       {link:'somewhere/management',title:'Management'},
       {link:'somewhere/cloud',title:'Cloud'}

    ]
```